# Solving simultaneous equation involving quadratic and exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have two equations $y=x^2$ and $y=e^{x+1}$. I want to solve them simultaneously and find $x.$ But I am having trouble solving them. I have tried the following:
\begin{aligned}x^2&=e^{x+1}\\
\ln(x^2)&=x+1\\
2\ln(x)&=x+1\\
\ln(x)&=\frac{x+1}{2}
\end{aligned}
and then I have no more ideas.

Comment: You have an obvious solution, which is $x=-1$ . Studying variations of the function $x\mapsto e^{x+1}-x^2$ might give you that this is the unique solution (i've not checked)

Comment: It is $$x=-1$$ or $$x=-2 W\left(-\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: With the LambertW function.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner so there is no way of solving this algebraically? I will just have to see that there is a obvious solution $x=-1$?

Comment: I think there is no way, but $x=-1$ is algebraically solution, the other solution not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\le0$, the function $x^2$ is strictly decreasing, and the function $e^{x+1}$ is strictly increasing, so there is at most one solution. By inspection $x=-1$ is a solution, so there are no others for $x<0$.

For $x>0$ we want to show that $$e^{x+1}>x^2\quad(*)$$ so that there are no solutions for $x>0$. That would be easy with calculus, but the OP has classified it as precalculus, so we have to work a little harder.

Note first that $(x-1)^2>2$ for $x\ge3$, so (rearranging) $2x^2>(x+1)^2$. We claim that for any positive integer $n>3$ we have $2^n\ge n^2$. It is true for $n=4$. Assume it is true for $n$, then $2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n\ge2n^2>(n+1)^2$, so it is true for $n+1$ and hence for all $n$.

Now consider $4\le n<x<n+1$. We have $e^{x+1}>2^{x+1}\ge2^{n+1}\ge (n+1)^2\ge x^2$. So we have established (*) for $x\ge4$.

$(*)$ is obviously true for $0\le x\le 1$. It is true for $1\le x\le2$ because $e^{x+1}>2^{1+1}=4\ge x^2$. It is true for $2\le x\le 4$ because $e^{x+1}>2.7^3>16\ge x^2$.